# How to run this program for X11 on Mac OS?

Tags: gcc, x11, xquartz

Source:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

    Display *display;
    display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if(display == NULL){
      fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open display.\n");
      exit(1);
    }
    XCloseDisplay(display);
    return 0;
```

I tried compiling it on gcc "gcc $1.c -I/opt/X11/include   -L/opt/X11/lib -lX11",
but I couldn't.
Of course, I XQuartz was opened.
Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: is this complete source?  You need to include #include <X11/Xlib.h>.  What error did you get?

Comment: Sorry. Compile has succeeded.

Comment: But the program says "Cannot open display".

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile it as

```
gcc test.c -I /opt/X11/include -L /opt/X11/lib
```

and then before running it

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Comment: Thank you.After typed "export display=: 0", I succeeded.